# PHP Code for Email Comparison / Verification

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a function to compare two email fields.

As in :

```
Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$email?>"    
required> 

Confirm email : <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" 
onblur="confirmEmail()" value="<?=$email2?>" required>
```

Here is the JavaScript code I inserted into my HTML  :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function confirmEmail() {
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value
 var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value
 if (email != email2) {
 alert('Email Not Matching!');  }
    }
 </script>
```

The code works.

Once the user enters the second email address, localhost displays an alert, saying : "**Email not matching**"

For extra-measure, I inserted the following into the form's properties : **onsubmit="return confirmEmail()**

So, if the user ignores the first warning, he gets a second warning when he tries to press the SUBMIT button.

Unfortunately, this is where I am stuck. Because : after the second warning, if the user still does not modify the "confirm email" , the SUBMIT button still works The form gets sent.

How can I modify the code, so that : the error message continues to display until the user changes the email2 correctly??

(I tried using the WHILE function, and the DO....WHILE function. They worked............except that, the error-message kept displaying over and over.........and did not allow me to make the required correction to the email field (haha). I had to close the window completely)

Comment: does any one not copy and paste? thes forms are so anoying

Comment: "PHP Code for Email Comparison " this is pure javascript, or did you realy want php?

Comment: @Dagon Some sites (try to) block copy and paste actions on these fields — that's even more annoying

Answer (score 0):

I would submit the form with JavaScript.

```
<form>
  Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$email?>"    
required> 

  Confirm email : <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" 
onblur="confirmEmail()" value="<?=$email2?>" required>
</form>

<button onclick="formSubmit()">Learn More</button>
```

Your formSubmit() function would simply pull in the values and submit them after the proper check. This way, regardless of what the user enters, it has to go through your verification before it is submitted.

```
function formSubmit() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
  if (email != email2) {
  alert('Email Not Matching!');  
} else {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/Your/Path/To/Your/Form-Processing/?email="+email,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The function above will go in your script tags. It checks `email` and `email2` against each and then submits `email` with GET to the processing page the same way your form would. You can also pass other variables the same way by getting them with `document.getElementById('#id').value` and then send them through the GET method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, SRing.   I'm very new to this; but, where exactly is that function  "formSubmit()"  defined ??

Comment: Edited to include info about `formSubmit()`

Answer (score 0):

First, give your submit button an ID like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="mySubmit" disabled="disabled">
```

And in your if block add:

```
if (email !== email2) {
  alert('Not matching')
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
}else{
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Joey !!!  Actually, your code worked well.  The only problem is :  with the "Submit" button disabled, the user is not exactly sure :  where did he go wrong ???   LOL.   He knows there is something wrong with the form,  as the "submit" button is not working.  But, unless he is somehow informed that the emails do not match,  he wont know what to look for ))   (Although, it should be very obvious, of course; but, still, I am trying to create a Form which is as user-friendly as possible)

Comment: Look into the Foundation framework as they have a javascript validator built into their form.  It can help you make a user-friendly form and also help you structure your HTML.  Or you can keep on adding to your solution here... Ultimately you need to rely on server side validation (PHP/etc) as well as client-side JS validation... Typically browsers are getting smarter and they are doing this for you.  You can add things like required="required" to your inputs and modern browsers will do simple validation for you and require the user inputs the field.

Comment: I am already using the "Required" feature.  But, that does not help me when I am trying to "Match Emails" --- meaning, to ensure that the second email  (confirm email) is the same as the first one.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. Foundation has a JS plugin called Abide that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var count=0;

 function confirmEmail() {
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value
 var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value

 function chkEmail(){
     if (email != email2 && count==0)
       { alert('Email Not Matching!'); count++ }
     else if(email!=email2 && count ==1)
       //display warning
   }
chkEmail();
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dhruv Ramani.  Unfortunately, your code does not work.  :((((

Answer (score 0):

try this bro,

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
Email : <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$email?>" required> 

Confirm email : <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" value="<?=$email2?>" required>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="return confirmEmail();"/>

</form>
```

and in java script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


 function confirmEmail() {
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;


     if (email != email2)
       { alert('Email Not Matching!');  return false; }
     else {
       return true;
      }

   }

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Umar.  I actually tried this code yesterday.  It worked fine..........but the problem was :  even after I got the alert message, and did NOT input the correct email,  I was still able to send/submit the form.  This is what I said in my original post.  I don't want the form to be submitted UNLESS the email fields match each other !!